# Page Loading Image after multiple ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, loading

I have given a loading image binded to ajax start/stop functions like this..

```
$('#LoadingImage').bind('ajaxStart', function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind('ajaxStop', function(){ 
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Now i have many ajax calls on my page under document.ready().so all ajax calls start at the same time..but ajax stop varies according to the results in the ajax..so what happens is

loading image appears and when one ajax call is complete the image is hidden and shows my main screen.. Is there a way to loading image till the final ajax call is complete ???

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#LoadingImage').on('ajaxStart', function(){
        $(this).show();
}).on('ajaxStop', function(){   
        $(this).hide();

});

$.ajax({
                url: http:www.google.com(for example i gave this url),
                data:JSON.stringify({login:{"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}}),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {  
$.each(data.GetRejectedRequestsMethodResult,function(key,val){
                              //some code

error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }

        }); // end $.ajax 


$.ajax({
                url: http:www.google.com(for example i gave this url),
                data:JSON.stringify({login:{"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}}),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {  
$.each(data.GetRejectedRequestsMethodResult,function(key,val){
                              //some code

error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }

            }); // end $.ajax 
$.ajax({
                url: http:www.google.com(for example i gave this url),
                data:JSON.stringify({login:{"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}}),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {  
$.each(data.GetRejectedRequestsMethodResult,function(key,val){
                              //some code

error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }

            }); // end $.ajax 
$.ajax({
                url: http:www.google.com(for example i gave this url),
                data:JSON.stringify({login:{"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}}),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {  
$.each(data.GetRejectedRequestsMethodResult,function(key,val){
                              //some code

error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }

            }); // end $.ajax 

$.ajax({
                url: http:www.google.com(for example i gave this url),
                data:JSON.stringify({login:{"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}}),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {  
$.each(data.GetRejectedRequestsMethodResult,function(key,val){
                              //some code

error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }

            }); // end $.ajax
```

Like the above i have many ajax calls...The problem is that after the first ajax is complete the image hides..

Comment: first off, `.bind` is depricated, use `.on` function for that

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this? that will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up one variable which increments on Ajax start and decrements on Ajax complete.
Inside the ajaxStop function  check whether this variable is 0 or not.If zero then only hide the image.

Do like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var count=0;
  $('#LoadingImage').on('ajaxStart', function(){
      count++;
     if(count===1){
         $(this).show();
     }
  }).on('ajaxStop', function(){
     //count is decrementing and on same time checking whether it becomes zero
     if(!--count){
       $(this).hide();
     }
  });

  //suppose 10 simultanious ajax calls
  for(var j=0;j<10;j++){
     $.ajax({
     //configure whatever you want
     });   
  }
});
```

this should work (theoretically).

Comment: variable incremented inside my ajax cannot be accessed outside of it...If i give an alert to learn its value it alerts wrong value..

Comment: Declare the variable out side the ajax function. If you are facing issues again share the modified code so that it is easy to debug.

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey please use jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com to replicat the problem you are facing. that will give you better answers

Comment: @Dinoop paloli : Thnk u so much 4 d effort..i have 8 ajax calls in my page..All ajax calls are given in the document.ready() function.
so all my ajax calls start at the same time on document.ready() but the end time varies..one may fetch less records and end in 2milliseconds and some may have to fetch many records and may take 12milliseconds...!! this is my case..can u edit the above code u ve given according this case ??

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey I think you have not tested my code. Let me explain. Suppose 8 calls started at a time, then the count variable increments to 8 like 1,2,---8. When first Ajax call started the image becomes visible `(count==1)` . when each Ajax call ends it will decrements into 7,6,5--- to 0 . When zero comes It means that all calls are succeeded `(!--count)`. So the image will hide.

Comment: @Dinooppaloli : Thnks for the explanation buddy..i ll try it for sure and give you my result.

Comment: @Dinooppaloli: should i give the for loop also ?? or ajax start/stop functions alone are enough ?

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey No need to give the loop. It just for explanation.You can make your Ajax calls one by one.

Comment: @Dinooppaloli: Okay dude..It worked..But i have another similar issue..R u willinng to solve it ? anyways i have marked this as an answer..If u agree i will update my question now..!!

Comment: @PraveenGodfrey.if it is totally different question ask it as separate question.If that issue comes because of the answer that I made mention it here.